# Invoke Javascript method from code-behind based on a condition.

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

This is my javascript method in .aspx file. I want to invoke this method from code-behind based on a certain condition:

```
function confirmboxAndHideMessage() {
    //HideMessage();
    var response = confirm("are you sure?.");
    if (response == true) {
        document.getElementById("<%=chkValidated.ClientID%>").checked = true;
        HideMessage();
    }
    else {
        HideMessage();
        return true;
    }
}
```

The condition upon which I want to invoke is something like this:

```
        if (obj.fkValidationStatusId.HasValue && obj.fkValidationStatusId.Value.Equals(1))
        {
            btnProceedAddNewRecords.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "javascript:return confirmboxAndHideMessage();");  
        }
        else
        {
            btnProceedAddNewRecords.Attributes.Remove("OnClick");
        }
```

This condition is being exercised in a method which is called in PageLoad event inside

```
if (!IsPostBack) { /* condition */ }
```

It is not working and my guess is that the way i am adding the method in button attribute is wrong. My request is that, kindly suggest a way I can invoke this javascript method from my code-behind based on the stated condition. If you think that my approach is flawed, Please do suggest Alternatives. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use to set/unset  `OnClientClick`

```
if (obj.fkValidationStatusId.HasValue && obj.fkValidationStatusId.Value.Equals(1))
  {
     btnProceedAddNewRecords.OnClientClick="return confirmboxAndHideMessage();";  
  }
else
  {
     btnProceedAddNewRecords.OnClientClick="retun false;";
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following code where the condition is like

```
 public void test()
{
    String name = "test";
    if (name == "test")
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "hdrEmpty", "if(confirm('are you sure you want to continue?')==true){ Testfunction(); };", true); return;
    }
}
```

I am sure it will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for replying to my query. Please explain what "hdrEmpty" and "this.GetType()" parameters do?

Comment: @ebad86 "this.gettype" its return the type of current instance. And "hdrempty" its a key(that is unique identifier to script block), you can add at place of "hdrempty" whatever you want but unique. that recognize your event.

Answer (score 1):

You should return `true` or `false` from the function. You probably want to return true for a positive response:

```
function confirmboxAndHideMessage() {
  var response = confirm("are you sure?.");
  if (response == true) {
    document.getElementById("<%=chkValidated.ClientID%>").checked = true;
    HideMessage();
    return true;
  } else {
    HideMessage();
    return false;
  }
}
```

Use lowercase for the event name (as XHTML is picky about that), and remove `javascript:` from the code:

```
btnProceedAddNewRecords.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirmboxAndHideMessage();");
```

Put the code that sets the attribute outside the check for `IsPostBack`, otherwise it will not be updated when the condition changes.